# Azure Queue, AddMessage then UpdateMessage

Tags: azure-queues, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

Is it possible to Add a message to an Azure queue then, in the same flow, update or delete that message?

The idea would be to use the queue to ensure that some work gets done - there's a worker role monitoring that queue.  But, the Web role which added the message may be able to make some progress toward (and sometimes even to complete) the transaction.

The worker would already be designed to handle double-delivery and reprocessing partially handled messages (from previous, failed worker attempts) - so there isn't a technical problem here, just time inefficiency and some superfluous storage transactions.

So far it seems like adding the message allows for a delivery delay, giving the web role some time, but doesn't give back a pop-receipt which it seems like we'd need to update/delete the message.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature was added as part of the ["2016-05-31” REST API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-queues-new-feature-pop-receipt-on-add-message/)

> we now make pop receipt value available in the Put Message (aka Add Message) response which allows users to update/delete a message without the need to retrieve the message first.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you follow these steps as it worked for me

How to: Create a queue
A CloudQueueClient object lets you get reference objects for queues. The following code creates a CloudQueueClient object. All code in this guide uses a storage connection string stored in the Azure application's service configuration. There are also other ways to create a CloudStorageAccount object. See CloudStorageAccount documentation for details.

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
```

Use the queueClient object to get a reference to the queue you want to use. You can create the queue if it doesn't exist.

```
// Retrieve a reference to a queue
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

How to: Insert a message into a queue
To insert a message into an existing queue, first create a new CloudQueueMessage. Next, call the AddMessage method. A CloudQueueMessage can be created from either a string (in UTF-8 format) or a byte array. Here is code which creates a queue (if it doesn't exist) and inserts the message 'Hello, World':
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

```
// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a message and add it to the queue.
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello, World");
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

For more details, refer this link.
    http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/

Girish Prajwal